# Convert a folder of .txt files to .xlsx in python with plots

Tags: python, excel, text

I have a folder of ~1000 .txt files that contain data, which I'd like plotted the same way. This requires 3 challenges for me:
1) Convert .txt to .xlsx (or .xls - I don't care)
2) Doing step 1 in one shot instead of typing in the file name for every file I want to convert
3) After converting a file, I need excel to recognize the numbers as numbers and not as text (i.e. currently I have to manually enter the "text to columns" function on excel, which is annoying for 2 columns of ~1000 spreadsheets)

I have 2 codes which have come close (I found some other code online).

Code 1:

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
import csv
import openpyxl
import xlsxwriter


mypath = 'C:/desktop/Text Documents/'


from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
textfiles = [ join(mypath,f) for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) and '.txt' in  f]
for textfile in textfiles:
    f = open(textfile, 'r+')
    row_list = []
    for row in f:
        row_list.append(row.split('\t'))
    column_list = zip(*row_list)
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')
    i = 0
    for column in column_list:
        for item in range(len(column)):
            worksheet.write(item, i, column[item])
        i+=1
    workbook.save(textfile.replace('.txt', '.xls'))
```

The above takes a folder of textfiles and converts them to .xls, and delimits them, but unfortunately I still have to use the "text to columns" function

Code 2:

```
import csv
import openpyxl
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd

input_file = 'C:/desktop/Text Documents/thisismytextfilename.txt'
output_file = 'C:/desktop/Text Documents/thisismytextfilename.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

with open(input_file, 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        ws.append(row)


wb.save(output_file)

file_location = output_file

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0) #2 indicates 3rd page

x = [sheet.cell_value(i+14, 0) for i in range(sheet.nrows-14)]
y = [sheet.cell_value(i+14, 1) for i in range(sheet.nrows-14)]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file_location)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})

# Add the worksheet data that the charts will refer to.
headings = ['Time (s)', 'Load (kg)']
data = [x,y]

worksheet.write_row('A1', headings, bold)
worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])

chart1 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter'})

# Configure the first series.
chart1.add_series({
    'name': '=Sheet1!$B$1',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$25000',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$25000'})

chart1.set_x_axis({'name': 'Time'})
chart1.set_y_axis({'name': 'Load'})
chart1.set_style(1)

# Insert the chart into the worksheet (with an offset).
worksheet.insert_chart('D2', chart1, {'x_offset': 25, 'y_offset': 10})

workbook.close()
```

This extracts the 2 columns of data that I want and creates a plot. But I have to copy/paste the filename for every file and I have to go through and click "text to columns" every time.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to go through and click "text to columns" every time.

You can use the XlsxWriter [constructor](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#constructor) parameter `strings_to_numbers` to avoid this:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename, {'strings_to_numbers': True})
```